# How does Breadth First Search find shortest path from source vertex to destination vertex?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I was told that BFS can give you the shortest path from the source vertex to the destination vertex, which makes sense since you traverse the adjacent nodes. However, I do not see how that is guaranteed to happen always. Nowhere in the BFS pseudocode logic do I see to pick the correct adjacent node to guarantee to have the shortest path. BFS could pick any random adjacent node and end up with the longer path from the source vertex to the destination vertex. Then how does BFS give the shortest path from the source vertex to the destination vertex?

Comment: Is your graph weighted, or unweighted? BFS is only guaranteed to give you the shortest path for an **unweighted** graph (or a graph in which all edges have equal weight). For a weighted graph, BFS will not, in general, give you the shortest path.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Using BFS alone does not guarantee to find the shortest path.

It will only fetch you the shortest path when all the edges have an equal edge weight in the case of a weighted graph. For unweighted graphs, you can assume equal edge weights.

Other algorithms (for example, Dijkstra’s algorithm) adapt BFS to find the shortest paths.

**Thanks to your question, which pushed me to come up with an interesting case, where BFS can actually fetch you the shortest path in case of weighted graphs:**

When we have a **linear weighted undirected graph** (with **no cycles**), i.e., a graph with 2 adjacent nodes for middle nodes and 1 adjacent node for nodes are the extreme ends (like a double linked list), BFS could actually fetch us the shortest path.

**PS:** BFS does not pick up any adjacent node **randomly**. The adjacent node's selection depends on the adjacent nodes' order in the particular node's adjacency list. So, it's dependent on your code implementation and not on some random factor.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of unweighted graphs, it is guaranteed that eventually, we will get the shortest path using BFS.

But in the case of a weighted graph, we can still run a variant of BFS, i.e., using a priority queue for neighbors nodes (based on weights of edges). This variant is called [Dijkstra’s algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-algorithm-for-adjacency-list-representation-greedy-algo-8/).